# Optional argument objective C

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have an implemented method, say XXX that currently takes no argument and manipulates some data using a hard-coded parameter.

I am calling this method in multiple places in my code.

Now I want to add some flexibility where the method takes on an argument that determines the parameter instead of using the hard-coded value.  But I still want my existing code to work.  Basically, I want to just modify the method by adding an argument and saying that if method is called without argument, then assume the hard-coded value.

Looks like only way to do it is to duplicate the code and create a new method.  I.e have two methods the original one and new one without argument.  is there some other way to do this without duplicating code?

Answer (score 7):

```
- (void)XXX {
    [self XXX:42];
}

- (void)XXX:(NSInteger)value {
    // ...
}
```

Now you can either call

```
[blah XXX];
```

or

```
[blah XXX:39];
```